# Windows 10: Extend taskbar on multiple displays

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I would like to know if there is an option in Windows 10 that allows me to extend the taskbar (NOT duplicate it) on multiple displays, in order to have the Windows button on the far left of my first monitor, the clock on the far right of my last monitor, and one looooong taskbar with the open windows that spans across my multi-monitor setting.

I tried to in the options with no result, and also my google-fu was not sufficient to answer this question.

PS: Please note that I do NOT want to duplicate the taskbar, but to extend it in order to pass the limits of the monitor.

Comment: there are some programs that make windows treat many extended displays as one large one (usually for gamers). Sounds like this could help you here. It'd mean that maximizing a window would maximize it across all displays which is kinda frustrating, but it's a possible solution if you're willing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible without 3rd party software. Only option is to duplicate taskbar or to show taskbar only on main monitor, which are not options you desired.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on empty taskbar space> Taskbar settings, scroll down to "Show taskbar buttons on" select> Taskbar where window is open. That are the best You can get in windows without any app.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on the taskbar.
2. From pop-up menu select bottom line- Taskbar options.
3. On right side of the page, scroll down to "Notification area".
4. Click "Select which icons appear on the taskbar".
5. The first option from the top is "Always show all icons in the notification area". Turn it on.